# How to get svg imbeded code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to change the embedded SVG fill color and use JavaScript to achieve them. but it print nothing in console when i want to access innerHtml of object tag.

My HTML  code is-

```
   <object type="image/svg+xml" data="imageedit_3_7291031266-2.svg" id="svg_content"></object>
```

and JavaScript code  is -

```
    var a = document.getElementById('svg_content');
    console.log(a.innerHTML);
```

imageedit_3_7291031266-2.svg file code is-

```
  <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
  <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="667px" height="700px" viewBox="0 0 6670 7000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
   <g id="layer101" fill="#3b3f60" stroke="none">
   <path d="M3390 6629 c-19 -4 -41 -6 -48 -4 -7 3 -45 0 -85 -5 -40 -5 -252 -16 -472 -25 -564 -22 -759 -46 -884 -110 -92 -46 -107 -83 -86 -204 23 -125 45 -276 52 -356 3 -38 9 -74 13 -80 4 -5 10 -107 14 -225 6 -209 25 -493 67 -1045 22 -277 21 -449 -1 -750 -11 -136 -53 -520 -72 -640 l-12 -80 -7 60 c-4 42 -19 84 -47 140 -42 81 -89 227 -112 345 -7 36 -28 135 -47 220 -20 85 -37 175 -39 200 -8 86 -36 274 -44 296 -5 12 -14 75 -20 140 -6 66 -19 173 -30 239 -49 311 -60 437 -60 696 -1 140 -5 286 -10 324 -5 39 -12 93 -16 120 -3 28 -20 84 -36 125 -37 89 -47 197 -26 275 21 76 11 107 -37 123 -96 31 -385 19 -430 -18 -11 -9 -14 -45 -14 -153 -1 -157 -4 -174 -50 -264 -22 -45 -31 -76 -31 -112 0 -28 -9 -90 -21 -138 -19 -79 -20 -104 -13 -248 8 -185 8 -199 -7 -565 -6 -151 -8 -369 -5 -485 4 -115 9 -295 12 -400 6 -230 17 -349 49 -520 13 -71 29 -168 35 -215 11 -86 26 -162 99 -500 65 -303 100 -450 126 -535 13 -44 54 -196 90 -337 85 -335 143 -493 214 -582 17 -21 28 -43 24 -49 -3 -5 -1 -7 4 -4 6 4 19 -3 29 -14 32 -36 123 -93 249 -158 66 -34 156 -82 200 -107 44 -26 133 -73 198 -105 103 -52 117 -62 117 -85 0 -19 8 -28 34 -39 66 -28 155 -96 260 -198 87 -85 123 -113 191 -147 50 -25 93 -40 105 -37 10 3 39 -2 62 -10 33 -11 64 -13 133 -7 116 9 115 9 150 23 53 21 59 22 128 31 59 7 83 5 163 -15 52 -14 149 -31 216 -40 67 -9 125 -18 128 -20 13 -8 171 23 188 37 9 8 39 24 66 34 64 25 134 89 171 155 28 52 34 57 145 111 63 32 136 67 162 77 49 20 68 43 61 70 -3 12 39 41 169 116 95 54 205 120 243 146 39 26 102 64 140 85 83 45 165 119 211 190 106 164 274 878 425 1799 6 33 19 105 30 160 19 92 30 171 60 435 24 213 36 554 32 955 -5 587 -36 883 -108 1047 -40 91 -42 108 -15 133 26 24 25 65 -2 112 -20 33 -23 52 -23 153 0 63 4 145 9 182 l8 67 -43 12 c-63 18 -332 17 -384 -2 l-40 -14 3 -140 c4 -156 -3 -186 -59 -250 -37 -42 -40 -72 -9 -115 21 -29 22 -35 11 -90 -7 -33 -21 -86 -32 -117 -14 -39 -23 -102 -29 -193 -41 -660 -89 -1213 -116 -1360 -8 -41 -14 -90 -14 -109 0 -18 -7 -59 -15 -90 -8 -31 -15 -74 -16 -96 -1 -22 -13 -67 -27 -99 -13 -34 -28 -99 -34 -150 -10 -96 -32 -184 -79 -327 -16 -48 -29 -97 -29 -110 0 -43 -11 -10 -25 72 -19 122 -27 301 -17 401 4 49 4 95 -1 103 -5 9 -4 15 3 15 6 0 10 28 10 73 0 80 -8 120 -21 111 -5 -3 -6 9 -2 27 3 17 1 34 -4 38 -6 3 -13 26 -17 51 -10 76 -23 129 -33 142 -5 7 -6 24 -2 38 5 20 7 21 8 6 1 -14 4 -17 11 -10 16 16 30 198 36 454 2 129 9 257 15 284 6 33 6 53 -1 61 -7 9 -7 14 -1 17 6 2 12 68 15 163 5 194 23 453 36 515 5 25 6 95 3 155 -4 82 -1 125 10 170 9 33 20 95 26 138 6 43 18 91 26 107 20 39 19 85 -2 111 -71 86 -446 165 -873 184 -74 3 -207 10 -295 16 -88 5 -199 11 -247 12 -47 1 -84 5 -81 10 2 4 3 7 1 6 -2 -1 -19 -5 -38 -10z"/>
  </g>
  <g id="layer102" fill="#d4d5d9" stroke="none">
   <path d="M3390 6629 c-19 -4 -41 -6 -48 -4 -7 3 -45 0 -85 -5 -40 -5 -252 -16 -472 -25 -564 -22 -759 -46 -884 -110 -92 -46 -107 -83 -86 -204 23 -125 45 -276 52 -356 3 -38 9 -74 13 -80 4 -5 11 -113 15 -240 4 -126 13 -300 21 -385 12 -143 13 -147 10 -47 -3 74 0 107 8 107 6 0 5 4 -3 9 -13 8 -13 12 -1 26 12 14 12 18 -1 26 -9 5 -9 9 -2 9 7 0 10 14 8 39 -2 21 3 51 11 66 9 17 11 31 5 34 -11 7 -8 101 3 120 4 6 2 18 -4 26 -8 9 -8 20 -2 31 6 11 7 27 1 41 -6 15 -5 23 2 23 7 0 9 11 5 28 -4 18 -3 22 3 12 5 -8 14 -69 20 -135 18 -181 22 -209 32 -219 12 -13 11 -29 -1 -21 -14 9 -12 -8 3 -24 10 -11 10 -13 0 -7 -7 4 -13 2 -13 -3 0 -6 7 -11 15 -11 18 0 18 -1 1 -36 -8 -15 -12 -32 -9 -38 4 -5 10 -1 14 10 7 17 8 16 9 -6 2 -14 2 -30 1 -37 -1 -6 3 -14 9 -18 6 -4 10 7 11 27 0 30 1 31 10 10 5 -13 14 -20 20 -17 6 4 8 13 5 21 -3 8 -1 14 3 14 5 0 15 -15 22 -32 7 -18 15 -37 17 -42 3 -5 -2 -7 -11 -3 -9 3 -18 0 -21 -9 -3 -8 -1 -14 4 -14 6 0 10 -4 10 -10 0 -5 -9 -10 -20 -10 -11 0 -20 -7 -20 -16 0 -8 5 -12 10 -9 16 10 12 -7 -5 -19 -16 -12 -10 -60 7 -50 5 3 8 0 7 -7 -4 -21 12 -130 22 -148 8 -16 33 -72 62 -141 16 -41 178 -340 197 -365 4 -5 31 -57 60 -115 30 -58 56 -107 60 -110 4 -3 4 -25 1 -50 -4 -28 -9 -40 -14 -32 -5 6 -6 12 -3 12 3 0 -1 12 -9 27 -8 15 -11 31 -8 36 3 5 -7 20 -22 33 -16 13 -25 24 -22 24 12 0 -34 94 -53 107 -15 11 -48 65 -56 93 -10 35 -18 50 -30 54 -8 3 -14 12 -14 20 0 9 -10 25 -23 36 -12 12 -22 27 -22 33 0 7 -7 12 -15 12 -8 0 -21 6 -29 13 -12 12 -12 15 0 23 11 7 9 10 -8 15 -13 4 -23 10 -23 14 0 5 -8 11 -17 13 -14 4 -12 5 5 6 12 0 22 3 22 6 0 17 -33 66 -52 76 -19 10 -20 9 -15 -10 4 -18 2 -21 -14 -16 -16 5 -19 1 -19 -24 0 -17 5 -31 10 -31 6 0 10 -5 10 -11 0 -6 -7 -9 -15 -5 -8 3 -15 1 -15 -4 0 -6 5 -10 10 -10 6 0 10 -5 10 -11 0 -5 -5 -7 -11 -3 -6 3 -15 0 -20 -7 -13 -21 -11 -29 6 -23 11 5 15 -1 15 -20 0 -19 -5 -26 -20 -26 -12 0 -20 -7 -21 -17 -1 -35 -10 -108 -16 -133 -6 -19 -8 -13 -13 30 -3 30 -6 -62 -6 -205 -2 -266 -11 -417 -39 -653 -9 -74 -15 -141 -13 -150 2 -10 12 54 23 141 l19 157 32 0 c31 0 53 23 33 35 -17 11 3 27 27 21 13 -4 24 -2 24 3 0 5 -10 11 -22 13 -12 2 -23 9 -26 17 -3 10 2 12 22 7 25 -6 32 1 27 27 -1 5 8 5 20 2 l21 -7 -21 21 c-17 17 -19 25 -11 41 14 26 21 25 56 -5 28 -24 28 -25 7 -25 -39 0 -25 -17 20 -24 40 -7 41 -8 22 -22 -19 -14 -17 -15 20 -11 27 3 39 9 37 18 -3 12 -1 12 10 1 11 -11 9 -16 -11 -31 -13 -10 -21 -23 -17 -30 5 -7 -1 -11 -13 -11 -12 0 -21 -4 -21 -10 0 -5 7 -6 17 -3 11 4 14 3 9 -6 -5 -8 -18 -10 -32 -7 -14 4 -24 2 -24 -4 0 -5 6 -10 13 -10 8 0 7 -3 -3 -10 -9 -6 -17 -5 -23 3 -6 8 -7 8 -4 -3 2 -8 19 -18 38 -22 29 -6 28 -7 -11 -4 -29 2 -50 -2 -58 -11 -11 -11 -10 -14 2 -19 9 -3 16 -15 16 -26 0 -15 -5 -19 -20 -15 -13 3 -20 0 -20 -9 0 -8 -5 -14 -11 -14 -6 0 -8 -8 -4 -20 7 -23 -10 -60 -29 -60 -8 0 -16 -10 -19 -22 -4 -12 -9 -19 -13 -15 -10 10 -33 -24 -34 -48 0 -15 7 -21 28 -23 l27 -1 -25 15 -25 15 25 -5 c14 -3 28 -6 33 -6 4 0 7 -9 7 -20 0 -14 7 -20 24 -20 13 0 27 -7 30 -16 9 -24 8 -26 -14 -19 -11 3 -20 2 -20 -3 0 -5 10 -12 23 -16 32 -8 35 -8 40 12 4 14 5 13 6 -4 0 -12 11 -26 24 -32 20 -10 18 -11 -20 -11 -23 -1 -44 3 -48 8 -3 5 -23 8 -45 6 -26 -2 -40 0 -40 8 0 7 -4 6 -9 -3 -13 -20 -3 -32 20 -25 11 4 33 1 49 -6 l29 -13 -26 -17 c-15 -10 -21 -19 -14 -23 6 -4 11 -1 12 6 0 7 4 4 8 -7 10 -25 -11 -35 -54 -27 l-30 5 19 -21 c11 -12 25 -22 33 -22 7 0 13 -7 13 -15 0 -15 -23 -11 -47 8 -7 5 -13 6 -13 1 0 -5 -5 -2 -10 6 -8 13 -10 12 -10 -2 0 -10 -6 -18 -13 -18 -11 0 -22 -18 -44 -75 -3 -5 0 -3 6 5 9 12 11 10 11 -12 0 -22 5 -28 21 -28 18 0 19 -2 9 -15 -9 -11 -10 -15 -1 -15 19 0 43 28 36 42 -3 7 2 3 11 -9 9 -13 24 -23 34 -23 9 0 27 -9 40 -20 18 -16 20 -20 7 -20 -10 0 -17 -6 -18 -12 0 -7 -4 -4 -9 7 -8 19 -9 19 -9 -3 -1 -18 3 -22 18 -17 21 6 71 -10 71 -24 0 -6 -11 -6 -30 1 -22 7 -34 7 -45 -2 -10 -9 -19 -9 -36 0 -19 11 -21 10 -16 -4 8 -21 -7 -21 -29 1 -16 16 -16 16 -10 -4 4 -13 1 -25 -11 -34 -11 -9 -14 -10 -9 -1 10 17 -9 15 -24 -2 -6 -8 -18 -12 -26 -9 -21 8 -17 -1 15 -36 19 -20 35 -29 45 -25 9 3 16 2 16 -3 0 -6 11 -15 25 -21 35 -16 31 -38 -7 -47 -30 -6 -31 -7 -12 -15 36 -14 42 -34 8 -26 l-29 6 30 -25 c23 -19 26 -25 13 -25 -10 0 -18 5 -18 10 0 6 -9 10 -20 10 -30 0 -24 -15 15 -36 40 -21 43 -29 15 -37 -13 -3 -20 0 -20 9 0 21 -43 35 -53 18 -5 -8 -12 -12 -18 -9 -5 4 -9 1 -9 -6 0 -7 -3 -9 -7 -6 -3 4 2 17 13 29 10 12 14 18 7 15 -6 -4 -13 -1 -16 5 -2 7 -9 -3 -14 -22 -8 -28 -6 -37 6 -47 14 -11 14 -12 -1 -13 -19 0 -22 -18 -11 -58 3 -14 9 -19 13 -13 4 8 13 5 25 -9 18 -20 18 -20 -19 -20 -30 0 -38 -5 -48 -27 -6 -16 -11 -45 -12 -65 0 -21 -4 -38 -7 -38 -7 0 -22 -40 -33 -93 -11 -46 -29 -20 -22 32 l6 46 -17 -45 c-12 -32 -16 -79 -16 -165 0 -134 17 -214 77 -360 45 -111 101 -193 240 -352 107 -122 144 -154 326 -287 12 -9 13 -8 4 4 -13 18 -14 50 -1 50 5 0 7 5 5 12 -5 13 35 58 50 58 4 0 27 -9 50 -20 22 -11 45 -20 50 -20 15 0 22 -27 22 -83 0 -52 13 -123 24 -134 3 -3 12 0 21 7 11 9 15 33 15 91 0 45 5 81 11 85 6 3 9 14 6 24 -3 13 3 20 22 24 22 5 91 81 91 100 0 3 10 16 23 29 12 13 38 44 57 70 19 25 41 46 48 47 6 0 12 11 12 25 0 19 5 25 23 25 15 0 18 3 9 8 -9 6 -6 12 11 21 12 6 36 33 52 59 16 26 46 68 67 93 21 26 38 52 38 58 0 6 5 11 10 11 6 0 10 10 10 23 0 13 4 27 9 32 5 6 14 27 21 48 7 21 14 37 16 34 4 -4 -50 -185 -66 -222 -63 -148 -140 -277 -199 -337 -20 -21 -47 -57 -59 -82 -23 -43 -23 -45 -5 -63 32 -32 19 -161 -27 -267 -11 -26 -20 -51 -20 -56 0 -13 39 -20 220 -36 131 -11 242 -14 445 -9 356 7 391 10 391 36 0 10 -3 19 -7 19 -7 0 -20 49 -24 90 -3 29 -63 198 -75 210 -8 8 -28 43 -47 80 -9 19 -23 39 -30 43 -7 4 -13 14 -13 21 0 7 -15 33 -32 57 -42 57 -58 85 -58 102 0 8 -13 25 -28 38 -15 13 -41 46 -56 72 -15 26 -38 52 -50 57 -13 5 -26 20 -30 34 -8 33 -103 130 -129 131 -12 1 -22 -6 -25 -17 -4 -15 -7 -17 -13 -6 -7 10 -9 9 -9 -4 0 -9 -5 -20 -12 -24 -8 -5 -9 -2 -4 12 47 123 119 380 122 438 4 75 13 93 41 81 16 -8 16 -9 -4 -12 -20 -4 -23 -11 -23 -48 0 -42 11 -57 38 -48 6 3 12 12 13 21 1 16 23 -68 33 -124 3 -13 8 -28 11 -34 4 -6 8 -26 11 -44 10 -85 117 -342 210 -508 18 -32 50 -91 70 -130 43 -82 86 -151 119 -188 13 -14 26 -42 29 -64 9 -46 14 -42 38 26 18 52 61 108 83 108 7 0 20 -9 30 -20 10 -11 50 -37 88 -58 64 -35 68 -39 63 -65 -8 -39 10 -73 30 -56 8 6 14 16 14 21 0 13 57 66 89 83 36 18 187 185 246 270 26 39 54 77 61 85 25 31 93 178 118 258 67 215 88 531 52 792 -10 69 -16 168 -15 220 2 85 -18 259 -39 345 -11 42 -4 75 16 75 14 0 13 2 -2 13 -17 13 -17 15 -2 45 9 18 16 33 16 34 -1 2 3 14 8 28 9 24 10 23 20 -20 l11 -45 -4 45 c-12 123 -15 264 -8 342 5 49 5 95 0 103 -5 9 -4 15 3 15 6 0 10 28 10 73 0 80 -8 120 -21 111 -5 -3 -6 9 -2 27 3 17 1 34 -4 38 -6 3 -13 26 -17 51 -10 76 -23 129 -33 142 -5 7 -6 24 -2 38 5 20 7 21 8 6 1 -14 4 -17 11 -10 16 16 30 198 36 454 2 129 9 257 15 284 6 33 6 53 -1 61 -7 9 -7 14 -1 17 6 2 12 68 15 163 5 194 23 453 36 515 5 25 6 95 3 155 -4 82 -1 125 10 170 9 33 20 95 26 138 6 43 18 91 26 107 20 39 19 85 -2 111 -71 86 -446 165 -873 184 -74 3 -207 10 -295 16 -88 5 -199 11 -247 12 -47 1 -84 5 -81 10 2 4 3 7 1 6 -2 -1 -19 -5 -38 -10z m7 -81 c8 -36 9 -85 4 -153 -4 -55 -7 -967 -5 -2027 3 -1506 1 -1928 -9 -1928 -9 0 -12 383 -14 1733 -1 952 -4 1795 -6 1872 -2 77 0 228 5 335 8 142 7 195 -1 198 -15 5 -14 22 2 22 7 0 18 -23 24 -52z m-1507 -137 c0 -10 -3 -21 -7 -25 -5 -4 -9 -20 -9 -34 -1 -15 -2 -33 -3 -39 0 -7 -8 -13 -18 -13 -9 0 -13 3 -10 6 4 4 -1 19 -10 34 -10 18 -13 34 -8 46 5 11 9 22 10 27 2 4 3 8 4 10 0 1 12 3 26 3 18 1 25 -3 25 -15z m1391 -27 c-9 -28 -9 -29 -10 -3 -1 14 2 29 6 32 11 12 13 2 4 -29z m-4 -126 c-2 -18 -4 -4 -4 32 0 36 2 50 4 33 2 -18 2 -48 0 -65z m-1357 53 c0 -12 -20 -25 -27 -18 -7 7 6 27 18 27 5 0 9 -4 9 -9z m24 -67 c5 -13 1 -15 -20 -10 -19 5 -30 2 -41 -11 -10 -13 -13 -14 -10 -3 3 13 42 39 58 40 4 0 10 -7 13 -16z m-9 -44 c-11 -5 -29 -9 -40 -9 l-20 0 20 9 c11 5 29 9 40 9 l20 0 -20 -9z m-28 -43 c4 -6 -2 -8 -15 -5 -14 4 -22 1 -25 -11 -3 -9 -5 -4 -6 11 -1 22 3 25 19 21 11 -3 23 -10 27 -16z m1368 -32 c-3 -26 -9 -45 -12 -42 -2 3 -1 26 2 52 4 25 10 44 12 41 3 -3 2 -26 -2 -51z m-1365 -10 c0 -6 5 -16 12 -23 14 -14 21 -52 10 -52 -4 0 -13 5 -20 12 -9 9 -12 8 -12 -4 0 -20 53 -41 68 -26 5 5 36 11 70 12 l60 2 -72 -31 c-108 -47 -120 -56 -66 -49 l45 6 -25 -18 c-13 -10 -31 -19 -40 -20 -8 -1 -23 -5 -32 -9 -11 -4 -18 -3 -18 4 0 6 5 11 10 11 6 0 10 7 10 15 0 8 -7 15 -15 15 -10 0 -15 10 -15 29 0 17 -4 32 -10 36 -5 3 -7 12 -4 19 3 7 6 26 8 42 2 16 4 32 5 35 2 11 31 6 31 -6z m1378 -455 c2 -129 1 -232 -1 -230 -2 3 -6 140 -9 305 -3 165 -2 269 1 230 3 -38 7 -176 9 -305z m-1318 227 c0 -18 -5 -23 -22 -22 -12 1 -23 6 -25 11 -3 8 5 14 45 33 1 0 2 -9 2 -22z m-2 -60 c-7 -14 -13 -17 -16 -9 -2 6 -10 12 -18 12 -28 0 -13 17 16 18 28 1 29 -1 18 -21z m73 -274 c-9 -15 -10 -12 -10 17 0 29 1 32 10 18 7 -12 7 -24 0 -35z m25 -72 c0 -10 -6 -18 -13 -18 -7 0 -13 11 -13 23 0 15 5 22 13 18 7 -2 13 -13 13 -23z m43 -2 c-22 -14 -33 -10 -19 6 7 8 17 12 22 9 6 -4 5 -10 -3 -15z m-25 -53 c9 3 16 2 16 -4 0 -16 -28 -22 -38 -9 -16 21 -24 43 -9 24 9 -10 21 -15 31 -11z m-24 -73 c-1 -35 -3 -44 -10 -32 -11 18 -9 79 3 79 4 0 7 -21 7 -47z m1227 -170 c-3 -10 -5 -2 -5 17 0 19 2 27 5 18 2 -10 2 -26 0 -35z m0 -80 c-3 -10 -5 -2 -5 17 0 19 2 27 5 18 2 -10 2 -26 0 -35z m0 -335 c-2 -13 -4 -5 -4 17 -1 22 1 32 4 23 2 -10 2 -28 0 -40z m1228 -190 c29 -64 61 -158 50 -147 -12 12 -95 189 -95 203 0 30 11 16 45 -56z m-2272 -62 c4 -10 0 -12 -14 -9 -10 3 -16 9 -13 14 8 13 21 11 27 -5z m1044 -163 c-2 -16 -4 -5 -4 22 0 28 2 40 4 28 2 -13 2 -35 0 -50z m-1261 -17 c3 -23 -20 -15 -24 8 -3 11 1 17 9 14 7 -2 13 -12 15 -22z m242 -880 c3 -3 2 -9 -2 -13 -4 -4 -11 -1 -16 7 -6 9 -10 10 -10 3 0 -6 5 -15 10 -18 6 -3 10 -14 10 -23 -1 -14 -5 -12 -21 7 l-20 25 4 -25 c2 -13 2 -18 0 -11 -3 6 -8 12 -13 12 -11 0 -21 30 -14 41 6 10 61 6 72 -5z m-78 -21 c0 -3 -9 -14 -20 -25 -13 -13 -20 -15 -20 -7 0 7 5 18 12 25 12 12 28 16 28 7z m-70 -25 c8 -5 11 -12 8 -15 -4 -4 -17 0 -30 9 -24 17 -5 23 22 6z m89 -67 c-1 -23 -2 -24 -6 -6 -2 12 -12 24 -21 26 -12 3 -10 5 6 6 18 1 22 -4 21 -26z m8 -105 c-3 -20 0 -41 6 -47 15 -15 -1 -14 -17 1 -7 7 -11 20 -8 30 2 10 -1 18 -6 18 -6 0 -16 8 -21 19 -9 16 -6 18 20 17 30 -1 31 -3 26 -38z m-117 -386 c0 -10 -4 -11 -12 -5 -7 6 -20 13 -28 16 -8 3 -3 5 13 4 16 -1 27 -7 27 -15z m476 -234 c-4 -62 -8 -129 -10 -148 -2 -19 -7 -134 -11 -255 -4 -121 -9 -223 -12 -227 -9 -15 -24 -8 -19 10 3 9 8 116 11 237 3 121 10 252 16 290 5 39 11 99 12 135 4 71 4 70 14 70 3 0 3 -51 -1 -112z m1619 -66 c1 -77 9 -187 16 -245 9 -79 10 -112 1 -129 -9 -20 -11 -15 -13 37 -1 33 -3 71 -5 85 -2 14 -5 107 -8 208 -3 101 -8 188 -12 195 -5 9 -4 9 5 1 8 -8 13 -58 16 -152z m-2215 9 c0 -12 -37 -29 -49 -22 -21 13 -2 38 25 33 13 -2 24 -7 24 -11z m1349 -231 c14 -66 8 -78 -8 -15 -6 25 -18 48 -26 51 -10 4 -15 20 -15 43 l0 36 19 -31 c10 -17 24 -54 30 -84z m-789 -385 c0 -8 -4 -15 -10 -15 -5 0 -10 7 -10 15 0 8 5 15 10 15 6 0 10 -7 10 -15z m910 -875 c0 -5 -9 -6 -20 -3 -15 4 -19 2 -14 -10 3 -9 1 -24 -5 -34 -9 -15 -10 -13 -5 11 5 21 4 27 -5 22 -6 -4 -11 -3 -11 3 0 5 -10 11 -22 13 -13 2 1 4 30 5 28 0 52 -3 52 -7z"/>
   <path d="M1886 6084 c-4 -9 -4 -19 -1 -22 3 -3 5 0 5 6 0 7 7 9 18 5 15 -6 15 -5 3 10 -17 21 -17 21 -25 1z"/>

 </g>

 </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

put the SVG directly inside your code and do js code

```
 <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="667px" 

height="700px" viewBox="0 0 6670 7000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
   <g id="layer101" fill="#3b3f60" stroke="none">
   <path d="M3390z"/>
  </g>
  <g id="layer102" fill="#d4d5d9" stroke="none">
   <path d="M3390 6"/>
   <path d="M1886 60 1z"/>

 </g>

 </svg>
<script>
    document.getElementById('layer101').style.fill = "#000"
    document.getElementById('layer102').style.fill = "#000"
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but i want to separate svg code from the html file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, If you want to change fill, You should include your SVG directly in DOM (object\img tag won't work for those cases).

You can do it manually by using svg tag instead of object
You can find some additional information here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Adding_vector_graphics_to_the_Web

Then you have two options: change fill color directly in svg code, or apply some css styles

```
svg g { fill: #d4d5d9 }
```

or you can use javascript to replace your object tag with an svg (simplified example)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('object').forEach((el) => {
  var url = el.getAttribute('data');
  
  fetch(url).then((res) => {
    var svgWrapper = document.createElement('div');
    svgWrapper.innerHTML = res;
    el.parentNode.replaceChild(svgWrapper, el);
  });
  
});
```

```html
 <object type="image/svg+xml" data="imageedit_3_7291031266-2.svg" id="svg_content"></object>
```